Determining the scroll offset of a widget X inside a Scrollable within the state of X
First of all, some optional context:
I am working on a certain aspect of our app where I need to be able to scroll to a certain widget inside a ListView. To be specific, I have a bunch of input categories (comprised of Cards with multimodal input Widgets like TextInputs or Take-Image-Buttons). At the very end of the ListView, I have a button labeled "What is still missing?". When the user clicks this button, the app validates the different categories, and subsequently should scroll up to the highest (e.g. lowest scroll offset) category that does not yet have valid input.
To achieve this, I created a bunch of different reactive components that amongst other things, allow widgets to "register" themselves with a callback that is supposed to determine their position within the ListView.
class _RoofSketchState extends State<_RoofSketch>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  static const _category = TqRoofCategory.roofSketch;
  final _key = GlobalKey();

  TqScrollMasterNineThousand? _scrollMaster;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _registerScrollEventCallback();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _unregisterScrollEventCallback();
    _scrollMaster = context.read<TqScrollMasterNineThousand>();
    _registerScrollEventCallback();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _unregisterScrollEventCallback();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Option<TqScrollMasterNineThousandScrollEvent> _createScrollEvent() {
    final scrollable = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);
    if ((scrollable, _key.currentContext)
        case (final scrollable?, final currentContext?)) {
      final renderBox = currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
      final scrollableBox = scrollable.context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
      if ((renderBox, scrollableBox)
          case (final renderBox?, final scrollableBox?)) {
        final offset =
            renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: scrollableBox).dy;

        return Some(
          TqScrollMasterNineThousandScrollEvent(
            scrollOffset: offset,
            onScrollToOffset: () {},
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    return const None();
  }

  void _registerScrollEventCallback() {
    _scrollMaster?.registerScrollEventCallback(
      category: _category,
      eventCallback: _createScrollEvent,
    );
  }

  void _unregisterScrollEventCallback() =>
      _scrollMaster?.unregisterScrollEvent(_category);

The implementation details of the class TqScrollMasterNineThousand are not relevant here. When the user clicks the button "What is missing?", the TqScrollMasterNineThousand invokes all registered callbacks, and attempts to scroll to the earliest scroll offset that was associated with a category that contained non-valid inputs.
My actual question
Consider this function that is supposed to serve as a callback that determines the scroll position of my widget within the next Scrollable inside the Widget tree:
  Option<TqScrollMasterNineThousandScrollEvent> _createScrollEvent() {
    final scrollable = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);
    if ((scrollable, _key.currentContext)
        case (final scrollable?, final currentContext?)) {
      final renderBox = currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
      final scrollableBox = scrollable.context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
      if ((renderBox, scrollableBox)
          case (final renderBox?, final scrollableBox?)) {
        final offset =
            renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: scrollableBox).dy;

        return Some(
          TqScrollMasterNineThousandScrollEvent(
            scrollOffset: offset,
            onScrollToOffset: () {},
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    return const None();
  }

I hoped this would work, and that renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: scrollableBox).dy; would evaluate to the scroll position. However, it returns NaN. I couldn't find any documentation on how I may be able to get the scroll position, so if anybody has an idea, please enlighten me.
Best regards

edit:
In case you just stumbled upon this and want a brief answer to the question

How to determine the scroll offset of my widget within its state?

The answer is
  double? _scrollOffsetOf(GlobalKey<State> key) {
    if (key.currentContext case final currentContext?) {
      final renderBox = currentContext.findRenderObject();
      final viewport = RenderAbstractViewport.maybeOf(renderBox);
      if ((viewport, renderBox) case (final viewport?, final renderBox?)) {
        return viewport.getOffsetToReveal(renderBox, 0).offset;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }



Thanks to the answer of Waseem, I've been able to figure out a solution.
Waseem's answer works in terms of scrolling to a specific child, but it wouldn't allow me to determine which child has the smallest scroll offset (and is thus the furthest up in my ListView). However, it has led me to investigate how Scrollable.ensureVisible works under the hood. And in its implementation, I've stumbled upon a function RenderAbstractViewport.getOffsetToReveal, which thankfully does exactly what it sounds like. With this function, I am able to determine the scroll offset of a specific RenderObject in my ViewPort. This is how I updated my _createScrollEvent() function:
  Option<TqScrollMasterNineThousandScrollEvent> _createScrollEvent() {
    if (_key.currentContext case final currentContext?) {
      final renderBox = currentContext.findRenderObject();
      final viewport = RenderAbstractViewport.maybeOf(renderBox);
      if ((viewport, renderBox) case (final viewport?, final renderBox?)) {
        final offset = viewport
            .getOffsetToReveal(
              renderBox,
              0, // scroll until top of target is visible
            )
            .offset;

        return Some(
          TqScrollMasterNineThousandScrollEvent(
            scrollOffset: offset,
            onScrollToOffset: () {},
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    return const None();
  }


I can't help with your code but I can suggest some packages. I have used 2 packages below and it work well. Hope this help:
https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list
https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index

You can assign the keys to each of your input widgets, for example:
final _nameFieldKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final _ageFieldKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final _uploadImageFieldKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

ListView(
       
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            key: _nameFieldKey,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your name';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            key: _ageFieldKey,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your age';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          ImageUploadField(
            key: _imageUploadFieldKey,
            //other attributes
          ),

          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if(!nameIsValid()) {
                   Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                     _nameFieldKey.currentContext!,
                     duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                   );
                }
              },
              child: const Text('Submit'),
          ),
      ],
)

and then use the Scrollable.ensureVisible method to scroll to a specific input field by key
Scrollable.ensureVisible(
   _nameFieldKey.currentContext!,
   duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
);

